# How can I generalize the Outer Class in Json Response mapping using REST template?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I'm developing a series of clients to webservices and I'm observing that they follow a simple json structure, like this:

```json
{
  "typex": { "property1" : "value"},
  "page": 1,
  "count": 200,
  "next_page": 2
}
```

I have near 15 webservices each returning the same structure, where the main information is within the object "typex" and their properties.
Today, these returns needs to have, at least, 2 classes, one for outer data and one for inner information.

```java
public class TypeXWrapper {
 @JsonProperty
 TypeX typex;
 @JsonProperty
 Integer page;
 @JsonProperty
 Integer count;
 @JsonProperty
 Integer next_page;
}
public class TypeX {
 @JsonProperty
 String property1;
}
```

In this way, it would be necessary to create 30 classes.
**Is there any way to implement some kind of generalization for situations like this?**

I was thinking something like:

```java
public class GenericWrapper<InnerClass> {
 @JsonProperty
 InnerClass data;
 @JsonProperty
 Integer page;
 @JsonProperty
 Integer count;
 @JsonProperty
 Integer next_page;
}
public class TypeX {
 @JsonProperty
 String property1;
}
```

But the problem is that the root property of the inner class data, changes for each webservice endpoint. That means that the next answer, for example TypeY, the property will have the name "typey", like:

```json
{
  "typey": { "property2" : "value"},
  "page": 1,
  "count": 200,
  "next_page": 2
}
```

Is there anything that I could use to achieve this generalization? *The environment and frameworks are Spring Boot 2.1.18 (can change if needed), using `resttemplate` with the return object encapsulated in `ParameterizedTypeReference`.*

Thanks!